# How to implement a custom NavigationViewController?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I want to implement a NavigationViewController, just like UINavigationViewController, but with no navigationBar and custom Push effect.

I know I should add the view controllers to my NavigationController as ChildViewController, and add their views into my NavigationController's view. However, I just can't handle the life cycle methods well, meaning when I push and pop a ViewController, the `viewWillAppeaer` `viewDidDisapper` and other methods should be call at proper time.

I try this in `popViewController:`:

```
    // life cycle
    currentVC.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    previousVC.viewWillAppear(animated)
    currentVC.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(self.durationOfPop, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut,
        animations: { () -> Void in

            // animations
            let width = currentVC.view.frame.width
            currentVC.view.frame = self.view.frame.rectByOffsetting(dx: width, dy: 0)
            previousVC.view.frame = self.view.bounds

        }) { (finished) -> Void in
            if finished {
                // life cycle
                currentVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
                currentVC.removeFromParentViewController()
                currentVC.didMoveToParentViewController(nil)
                previousVC.viewDidAppear(animated)

                //
                self.viewControllers.removeLast()
            }
    }
```

I call `viewWillDisappear:` explicitly to let it be called. But it has problems when the VC has child VC.

I also tried `transformFromViewController:toViewController...` method. It will let `viewWillAppear` execute within an animation block.

Comment: Why don't you just use `UINavigationViewController`, hide the navigation bar, and use a custom view controller transition?

Comment: You shouldn't ever or ever need to call methods like viewWillXXX,  its asking for trouble.